# Using git bash:Why is there an issue getting git clone to download a Foundation framework

Tags: git, bash, clone

I have tried and read everything I could find about the problem.
It happens as the last step of entering "`foundation new`" (without quotation marks) to start a new project.

I choose the template, I enter the project name, and then it says there is an issue, and to check the Git config on my computer and try again.
I really don't know how to solve this. Help would be appreciated.

Git,Nodejs, Bower and Gulp are installed and I verified that.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the exact error message, which probably is, according to [zurb/foundation-cli issue 54](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/issues/54).

```
Downloading the project template...There was an issue running git clone to download the....
Make sure your computer's Git is configured properly and then try again.
```

This coming from [`lib/commands/new.js#L70`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/blob/e0484a4b49d5ebf4b133121e8d136004855a6a3a/lib/commands/new.js#L70)

```
var cmd = format('git clone %s %s', repo, projectName);
```

Try and re-install everything:

> I'm up and running after a re-install of npm (4.5.0), then fresh install of foundation-cli (now 2.2.1).
>   I've chalked this to system config confusion, though a more meaningful error from foundation install would have been ideal.